# how to exit application using onbackpressed?

Tags: android, intentfilter, onbackpressed

I have two activities in my project.. I set intent-filter in my first activity..Now I have one button in my first activity,after click on that it will redirect to second activity..and I added some code in my second activity's onbackpress to close the app,but instead of close app it goes to first activity..can any one tell me what is mistake..

```
public class First extends ActionBarActivity {
private Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.first);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class Second extends Activity{


private Button btns;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    btns=(Button)findViewById(R.id.secs);
}

void Showtoast(String message) {
Toast.makeText(Second.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
private Boolean exit = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (exit) 
    {
        finish(); // finish activity
    } else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.close_app_example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".First"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="Second"></activity>
</application>
```

when i click on back button it shows first page instead of close app see images

[image]

[image]

Comment: use System.exit(0) in place of finish();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finish first activity when you are moving to second activity.

use

```
        Intent intent=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
        finish()
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

---

You need to intent your current context to another activity first with startActivity. After that you can finish your First activity,and move on to the next one so that when user presses the back button in the Second Activity,it closes the application,Add this piece of code under your btn.onClickListener in First.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.Class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // Call once you redirect to Second activity
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `First` after starting `Second` then you would finish `First`

```
public class First extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.first);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
});
```

}

Also I recommend you to read [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) to understand how it would be.